# Telemetry Collector not logging/exporting http calls

Tags: java, open-telemetry, telemetry

I am using Opentelemetry collector with below configuration which uses http receiver and export it to logs but when I call the API it returns 200 http code but in the console of collector I don't see any logs.

NOTE: I am using otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.68.0 Image

**collector-config.yaml**

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http: http://localhost:4318
      
exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      exporters: [logging]
      receivers: [otlp]
    metrics:
      exporters: [logging]
      receivers: [otlp]
    logs:
      exporters: [logging]
      receivers: [otlp]
  telemetry:
    metrics:
      level: detailed
```

**Http Call:**
POST: http://localhost:4318/v1/metrics

Request Body

```
{
    "resourceMetrics_": [
        {
            "resource_": {
                "attributes_": [
                    {
                        "key_": "loki.attribute.labels",
                        "value_": {
                            "valueCase_": 1,
                            "value_": "http.status",
                            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                            "unknownFields": {
                                "fields": {}
                            },
                            "memoizedSize": -1,
                            "memoizedHashCode": 0
                        },
                        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                        "unknownFields": {
                            "fields": {}
                        },
                        "memoizedSize": -1,
                        "memoizedHashCode": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "key_": "loki.resource.labels",
                        "value_": {
                            "valueCase_": 1,
                            "value_": "host.name, pod.name",
                            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                            "unknownFields": {
                                "fields": {}
                            },
                            "memoizedSize": -1,
                            "memoizedHashCode": 0
                        },
                        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                        "unknownFields": {
                            "fields": {}
                        },
                        "memoizedSize": -1,
                        "memoizedHashCode": 0
                    }
                ],
                "droppedAttributesCount_": 0,
                "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                "unknownFields": {
                    "fields": {}
                },
                "memoizedSize": -1,
                "memoizedHashCode": 0
            },
            "scopeMetrics_": [
                {
                    "scope_": {
                        "name_": "otelcol/hostmetricsreceiver/load",
                        "version_": "0.68.0",
                        "attributes_": [],
                        "droppedAttributesCount_": 0,
                        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                        "unknownFields": {
                            "fields": {}
                        },
                        "memoizedSize": -1,
                        "memoizedHashCode": 0
                    },
                    "metrics_": [
                        {
                            "dataCase_": 5,
                            "data_": {
                                "dataPoints_": [
                                    {
                                        "valueCase_": 4,
                                        "value_": 0.94,
                                        "attributes_": [
                                            {
                                                "key_": "loki.attribute.labels",
                                                "value_": {
                                                    "valueCase_": 1,
                                                    "value_": "http.status_code",
                                                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                                    "unknownFields": {
                                                        "fields": {}
                                                    },
                                                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                                                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                                                },
                                                "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                                "unknownFields": {
                                                    "fields": {}
                                                },
                                                "memoizedSize": -1,
                                                "memoizedHashCode": 0
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "startTimeUnixNano_": 1673933623000000000,
                                        "timeUnixNano_": 1673962743472355755,
                                        "exemplars_": [],
                                        "flags_": 0,
                                        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                        "unknownFields": {
                                            "fields": {}
                                        },
                                        "memoizedSize": -1,
                                        "memoizedHashCode": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                "unknownFields": {
                                    "fields": {}
                                },
                                "memoizedSize": -1,
                                "memoizedHashCode": 0
                            },
                            "name_": "system.cpu.load_average.15m",
                            "description_": "Average CPU Load over 15 minutes.",
                            "unit_": "1",
                            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                            "unknownFields": {
                                "fields": {}
                            },
                            "memoizedSize": -1,
                            "memoizedHashCode": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "dataCase_": 5,
                            "data_": {
                                "dataPoints_": [
                                    {
                                        "valueCase_": 4,
                                        "value_": 0.99,
                                        "attributes_": [
                                            {
                                                "key_": "loki.attribute.labels",
                                                "value_": {
                                                    "valueCase_": 1,
                                                    "value_": "http.status_code",
                                                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                                    "unknownFields": {
                                                        "fields": {}
                                                    },
                                                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                                                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                                                },
                                                "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                                "unknownFields": {
                                                    "fields": {}
                                                },
                                                "memoizedSize": -1,
                                                "memoizedHashCode": 0
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "startTimeUnixNano_": 1673933623000000000,
                                        "timeUnixNano_": 1673962743472355755,
                                        "exemplars_": [],
                                        "flags_": 0,
                                        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                        "unknownFields": {
                                            "fields": {}
                                        },
                                        "memoizedSize": -1,
                                        "memoizedHashCode": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                "unknownFields": {
                                    "fields": {}
                                },
                                "memoizedSize": -1,
                                "memoizedHashCode": 0
                            },
                            "name_": "system.cpu.load_average.1m",
                            "description_": "Average CPU Load over 1 minute.",
                            "unit_": "1",
                            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                            "unknownFields": {
                                "fields": {}
                            },
                            "memoizedSize": -1,
                            "memoizedHashCode": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "dataCase_": 5,
                            "data_": {
                                "dataPoints_": [
                                    {
                                        "valueCase_": 4,
                                        "value_": 0.81,
                                        "attributes_": [
                                            {
                                                "key_": "loki.attribute.labels",
                                                "value_": {
                                                    "valueCase_": 1,
                                                    "value_": "http.status_code",
                                                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                                    "unknownFields": {
                                                        "fields": {}
                                                    },
                                                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                                                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                                                },
                                                "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                                "unknownFields": {
                                                    "fields": {}
                                                },
                                                "memoizedSize": -1,
                                                "memoizedHashCode": 0
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "startTimeUnixNano_": 1673933623000000000,
                                        "timeUnixNano_": 1673962743472355755,
                                        "exemplars_": [],
                                        "flags_": 0,
                                        "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                        "unknownFields": {
                                            "fields": {}
                                        },
                                        "memoizedSize": -1,
                                        "memoizedHashCode": 0
                                    }
                                ],
                                "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                                "unknownFields": {
                                    "fields": {}
                                },
                                "memoizedSize": -1,
                                "memoizedHashCode": 0
                            },
                            "name_": "system.cpu.load_average.5m",
                            "description_": "Average CPU Load over 5 minutes.",
                            "unit_": "1",
                            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                            "unknownFields": {
                                "fields": {}
                            },
                            "memoizedSize": -1,
                            "memoizedHashCode": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "schemaUrl_": "",
                    "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
                    "unknownFields": {
                        "fields": {}
                    },
                    "memoizedSize": -1,
                    "memoizedHashCode": 0
                }
            ],
            "schemaUrl_": "https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.9.0",
            "memoizedIsInitialized": -1,
            "unknownFields": {
                "fields": {}
            },
            "memoizedSize": -1,
            "memoizedHashCode": 0
        }
    ],
    "memoizedIsInitialized": 1,
    "unknownFields": {
        "fields": {}
    },
    "memoizedSize": -1,
    "memoizedHashCode": 0
}
```

[image]

**Collector Logs:**
[image]

Comment: The 4th log line has a warning for the logging exporter, I would suggest updating your config to the logging exporter to not use the deprecated fields and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I have tried with verbosity: detailed but same issue,...

Comment: It was not working for me so I have tried with sending binary instead of json and worked smoothly (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/protocol/otlp.md#otlphttp)

Answer (score 0):

Use older OTLP collector version, which has older OTLP protocol version and you will get error response for your payload:

```
{
    "code": 3,
    "message": "unknown field \"unknownFields\" in v1.ExportMetricsServiceRequest"
}
```

Newer versions ignore unknowns fields silently, so you don't see any error.

Tested with `public.ecr.aws/aws-observability/aws-otel-collector:v0.21.0`